# Функция cblas_zgemm из библиотеки mkl

Tags: c++

Перемножаю одномерные массивы типа complex double.
Но не пойму, что ставить на место alpha и beta.
Если не при комплексных числах передаются 1.0 и 0.0, то тут не врублюсь.
Какие значения передать в функцию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `std::complex<double>(1.0)` P.S. возможно, для случая `alpha=1, beta=0` есть перегрузка, куда просто отдаются три указателя на массивы.

Comment: complex<double>(1.0) не катит, да и перегрузок нет. const void* нужен, не пойму, что им требуется.

Comment: У них там есть `MKL_Complex16`, в фунцкию просто надо отдать указатель на эту структуру.

Comment: Кстати, вы понимаете под одномерным массивом вектор? Тогде зачем вам матричное умножение?

Comment: матрица в виде:
`complex<double>*A = new complex<double>[size*size];`
Где обращение в виде
`A[i*size+j] = ...`

Comment: Результаты сходятся, потому что изначально матрица `C` у вас инициализирована нулями. А `beta` - это как раз коэффициент, на который умножается `C` поэлементно. Логичнее будет, если и действительная и мнимая части `beta` будут равны нулю.

Comment: Да, не стоит вносить правку в вопрос, публикуя решение. Для этого есть форма ответа. А код лучше приводить в виде текста, а не скриншотов.

Comment: ок, спасибо, понял

Answer (score 0):

Решил методом тыка, оказалось, что нужно было взять указатель на `complex<double>alpha и beta` и передать их в функцию. Скрины прилагаю 1 метод - стандартный из линейной алгебры, а второй с помощью функции cblas_zgemm():
Код:

```
complex<double>* method(const complex<double>* A, const complex<double>* B)
{
    complex<double>* C = new complex<double>[size * size];
    complex<double>a(1.0, 0.0);
    complex<double>alpha = &a;
    complex<double>b(0.0, 0.0);
    complex<double>beta = &b;
    cblas_zgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasTrans, size, size, size, alpha, A, size, B, size, beta, C, size);
    return C;
}
```

[image: Результат перемножения 2 матриц 10х10]